# Problem with categories on my blog website

Tags: python, django, categories, blogs

I have added categories and everything but I can't see any posts in my categories. When I open for example http://localhost:8000/category/sport/ it is showing no posts...

my urls.py :

```
from django.urls import path
#from . import views
from .views import HomeView , ArticleDetailView, AddPostView, UpdatePostView, DeletePostView, CategoryView

urlpatterns = [
    #path('', views.home, name="homepage"),
    path('', HomeView.as_view(), name = 'home'),
    path('article/<int:pk>', ArticleDetailView.as_view(), name = 'article-details'),
    path('add_post/', AddPostView.as_view(), name = 'add_post'),
    path('article/edit/<int:pk>', UpdatePostView.as_view(), name = 'update_post'),
    path('article/<int:pk>/delete', DeletePostView.as_view(), name = 'delete_post'),
    path('category/<str:categories>/', CategoryView, name='category'),
]
```

my models.py :

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.urls import reverse
from datetime import datetime, date

class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name 

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        #return reverse('article-details', args=(str(self.id)))
        return reverse('home')


class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    title_tag = models.CharField(max_length=255, default="YNTN")
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    body = models.TextField()
    post_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=255, default="uncategorized")

    def __str__(self):
        return (self.title + " | " + str(self.author))

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("home")

m
```

y views.py :

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView, CreateView, UpdateView, DeleteView
from .models import Post, Category
from .forms import PostForm, EditForm
from django.urls import reverse_lazy

#def home(request):
#    return render(request, 'home.html', {})
    

class HomeView(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'home.html'
    #ordering = ['-id']
    ordering = ['-post_date']

def CategoryView(request, categories):
    category_posts = Post.objects.filter(category=categories)
    return render(request, "categories.html", {"categories": categories, 'category_posts': category_posts})

class ArticleDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'article.details.html'

class AddPostView(CreateView):
    model = Post
    form_class = PostForm
    template_name = 'add_post.html'
    #fields = '__all__'
    #fields = ('title', 'body')

class UpdatePostView(UpdateView):
    model = Post
    form_class = EditForm
    template_name = 'update_post.html'
    #fields = ('title', 'title_tag', 'body')

class DeletePostView(DeleteView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'delete_post.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('home')
```

my categories.html :

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
<head>
    <title>{{ categories }} category</title>
</head>

<h1>{{ categories }} category</h1>
<hr>

{% for post in category_posts %}
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="{% url 'article-details' post.pk %}">
            {{ post.title }}</a> - 
        {{ post.category }} - 
        {{ post.author.first_name }}
        {{ post.author.last_name }} - {{ post.post_date }}<br/>
        <!-- <small>{{ post.body | slice:":359" | safe }}</small> -->

        {% if user.is_authenticated %}
        <small><a href="{% url 'update_post' post.pk %}"> (Edit) </a></small> <small><a
            href="{% url 'delete_post' post.pk %}">(Delete)</a></small> <br/>
        {% endif %}
    </li>
</ul>
{% endfor %}

{% endblock %}
```

my forms.py :

```
from django import forms
from .models import Post, Category

choices = Category.objects.all().values_list('name', 'name')

choice_list = []

for item in choices:
    choice_list.append(item)

class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ('title', 'title_tag', 'author', 'category', 'body')

        widgets = {
            'title': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Enter the title of your article'}),
            'title_tag': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'author': forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control',}),
            'category': forms.Select(choices=choice_list , attrs={'class': 'form-control',}),
            'body': forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Enter the content of your article'}),
        }

class EditForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ('title', 'title_tag', 'author', 'body')

        widgets = {
            'title': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Enter the title of your article'}),
            'title_tag': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'author': forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control',}),
            'body': forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Enter the content of your article'}),
        }
```

Please help, it's important to me :D I'm really stuck. It is my first StackOverflow post :D

Comment: Try to debug what value for categories you are getting in CategoryView and second you can check whether sport catergory post is available in DB or not.If this is ok and data is filtered in view as per sport category then in tepmplate need to be checked whether it received a value for categories in it or not...

Answer (score 1):

The proper way to resolve, is to associate `Post` model with a `Category`:

models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    title_tag = models.CharField(max_length=255, default="YNTN")
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    body = models.TextField()
    post_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE) # this line
```

It is fine to use `<str:category_name>` but note that the names **MUST** correspond.

urls.py

```
path('category/<str:category_name>/', category_view, name='category'),
```

Beware of good practices when writing code. In `Python` classes uses `CamelCase` and functions `snake_case`.

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_list_or_404

def category_view(request, category_name):
    category_posts =  get_list_or_404(Post, category__name=category_name)

    return render(request, "categories.html", {'category_posts': category_posts})
```